# How do I localize a Qt qmldir plugin?

Tags: qt, plugins, localization, qml

My app has a GUI written in Qt QML and we've successfully internationalized it using `qsTr()` and Qt `.ts` files. Now we're adding third-party plugin support via Qt's [qmldir](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html) API. In the `.qml` files of the plugin, `qsTr()` works correctly only if the translation is already in the host application's `.ts` files. How can a third-party QML author add localized strings to their qmldir plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a `Translator` class to organize and load translations. I have a `QVariantMap` that holds language name and file name, then when I create my `Translator` I have to provide the source directory since that is a requirement to load translations. My class also takes care of storing in `QSettings` last language used.

Now, to answer your question, you can always translate the exact same way as if it was a regular application, on your project file you will have to add something like this:

**1 - List all your possible translations**

```
TRANSLATIONS = \
           translation_sp.ts \
           translation_fr.ts
```

**2 - Run lupdate to generate the actual translation files**

```
lupdate project.pro
```

**3 - Run lrelease**

Translate with Linguist and create the actual translations. In this example, this step will generate `translation_sp.qm` and `translation_fr.qm`

**4 - Deploy translations with your plugin**

Once you have the `.qm` files deploy them with your plugin, ideally you could standardize the naming, maybe always using `plugin_XX.qm`

**5 - Load plugin translation in application**

To do this you will have to know the path to the translation file and the filename, so if your plugin is installed in the Qt default directories and you standardized the translation filenames this should be simple

```
qTranslator.load("plugin_XX.qm", "PATH_TO_TRANSLATION_FILE")
app->installTranslator(qtTranslator);
```

I simplified this in my class. Here are the [header](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Iktwo/inventory/master/src/translator.h) and [source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Iktwo/inventory/master/src/translator.cpp) files of my `Translator` class, if you want to take a look.

And here's how you use it:

```
Translator translator(app.data(), "PATH_TO_TRANSLATION");
translator.addTranslation("SP", "plugin_XX.qm");
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("translator", &translator);
```

You can install multiple translators, so it will work for your application and your plugins. When I was writing my class I was not expecting different sources but you can modify it so that everytime you add a translation it will take a 2 letter code for the language, the filename and the path to it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I like this solution because it leverages all of Qt's built-in i18n. One negative consequence is that the plugin will load its translation after the host loads its translation. Qt looks up translations in reverse order of addition, so the plugin has the power to override the host's translations if they use the same strings. If the plugin authors are competent, that's probably OK, but if they use inferior translations (like machine translation) then it will harm the host.

Comment: You can always control the order, let's say you have the translations already, then you load a plugin, you can unload all the translations (without sending a signal that something has changed) and then load them in the order that you want.